# Создание серверной части. Какие аналоги на go из java

Tags: golang

Являтся ли фреймворк fasthttp аналогом Spring MVC в java ?

Comment: Скорее аналогом любого веб-сервера из Java: Undertow, Jetty, Ratpack. Т.е. непосредственно реализация HTTP.

Answer (score 0):

**fasthttp** - это отличный мультиплексор,  а не полноценный MVC фреймворк.